# calculating value of two variables in a percentage equation

Tags: vb.net

i am trying to programmatically find value of x and y in equation **146 + x + y divided by 7 = 28.13%** x and y contains any value between 19 and 43.
here is the code i am getting 25 for both x and y ,what am i doing wrong?

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim percentage, x, y, f As Integer
    Public Function GetRandom(ByVal Min As Integer, ByVal Max As Integer) As Integer
        Dim Generator As System.Random = New System.Random()
        Return Generator.Next(Min, Max)
    End Function
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        percentage = 28.13

        Do Until f = 4
            If (146 + x + y) / 7 = percentage Then
                MessageBox.Show(x)
                MessageBox.Show(y)
                f = 4
            End If
            x = GetRandom(19, 43)
            y = GetRandom(19, 43)

        Loop


    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        x = 19
        y = 19
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: `= 28.13%` - you know the meaning of the "%" sign? It means "*1/100". That means 50% == 0.5! Are you looking for 0.2813 or 28.13?

Answer (score 2):

1) You declared `percentage` as an integer but are trying to set it to 28.13, which is not an integer.

2) Don't keep recreating a new random object:

```
Public Class Form1
  Private Generator As New Random()

  Public Function GetRandom(ByVal Min As Integer, ByVal Max As Integer) As Integer
    Return Generator.Next(Min, Max)
  End Function
```

3) If you *have* to equal 28.13, then that probably won't work without declaring percentage as a decimal and then using Math.Round(...) on your equation, but even then, I don't think you will have any x and y integers that will satisfy the equation for *precise* equality.

Comment: 2) you mean i should create it outside loop and function? 3)would declaring percentage as double solve my problem?

Comment: @OmairIqbal For #2, yes, just create it once outside the loop.  For #3, your problem isn't solvable with integers.  If you plug your formula into a spreadsheet with your x and y values in the columns and rows, the closest you get is (19,32) (20,31) (21,30) ... (26,25) where your resulting number is 28.142857.  Even with rounding, you aren't going to get to 28.13.  Your x or y or both would have to be a decimal, too, but then you have a lot more range of numbers to pick from (19.00 - 43.00).

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for (x+y)=50.91 where x is in [19, 43] and y is in [19, 43].

Therefore, choose an x, and then y=50.91-x

There is no single solution to the equation you have shown.

Or are you actually asking for something else?

Comment: are you saying this equation cannot be solved mathematically? or there are many solutions to this problem ,isnt my way of solving this right? (sorry not a maths champion here)

Comment: The problem can be solved mathematically, but the result is a line on a graph not a single value for x and a single value for y.